# Subquery Returning Error

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to implement a subquery but am getting an error saying `only a single result allowed`. Am I implementing it wrong in the query or is the statement itself wrong?

The search should be returning the name of the recipe name that matches the code produced in the nested select statement

**Query**

```
    return db.rawQuery("select recipe_name from recipes where recipe_code in (select ingredients.recipe_code, ingredients._id from ingredients inner join kitchen on kitchen.ingredient_name = ingredients.ingredient_name)", null);
```

**Error**

```
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression (code 1): , while compiling: select recipe_name from recipes where recipe_code in (select ingredients.recipe_code, ingredients._id from ingredients inner join kitchen on kitchen.ingredient_name = ingredients.ingredient_name)
```

12-10 22:19:04.238 29209-29209/com.example.rory.prototypev2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are trying to return multiple columns for the sub query and it only will allow one column to be returned. Remove the ingredients._id

The query would return

```
recipe_code, _id
  123         5
```

You only want the code.

Comment: By removing `ingredients._id` I get `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist` when I try run the command

Comment: Sorry yes you are right, mistake on my end typing in the updated query, thanks